# IBM Container , "Connection refused" when SSH to the public IP

Tags: ssh, containers, ibm-cloud, connection-refused

I'm using IBM Bluemix and Docker.

**[My goal]** I want to create a container. I found from the website that we could use SSH to login as "root" user. So I guess I could also install maven and MySQL on this container. Though IBM Container is a Docker based file system, we could treat container just like a Linux virtual machine (please correct me if wrong).

I found a similar question [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/241975/connection-refused-error-when-accessing-to-public.html), where njleviere said that port 22 is closed. How do I determine if a port is open or closed? If it's closed, how do I open it? Also, I think that port 22 is actually open in my case.

**[Problem Description]** I mainly followed [this website](http://www.slideshare.net/JosephChang8/connect-to-blumix-docker-container-with-putty), but I'm using Ubuntu and SSH instead of Putty.

First, I create the key file with `ssh-keygen`. For the filename, I tried "cloud" and "cloud.key". Both failed. So I think the name for the key does not matter (please correct me if wrong).

I open the `.pub` key. There is a `"yu@yu-VirtualBox"` tag at the end of the key file. I am not sure if I should include this tag. So I tried several things:

1. `ssh-rsa KeyString yu@yu-VirtualBox`
2. `ssh-rsa KeyString`
3. `KeyString`

All failed.

Then I created the container. I choose the `"ibmliberty"`. Given the public IP I created before (already unbind from any containers), I added 22 to the public Port. And pasted the `"cloud.pub"` to the SSH key. After several minutes, the container started to run. The following two links are the screen shot for the Bluemix console on creating the container.

Then I could see the default page for port 9080 in browser for https://169.44.124.121:9080. It said "Welcome to Liberty" and "WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5.9".

Then I typed (cloud and cloud.pub is the key file)

> ssh -i cloud root@169.44.124.121

Then I get the

> ssh: connect to host 169.44.124.121 port 22: Connection refused

I used `cf ic ps` to check the port. It looks fine.
I see `169.44.124.121:22->22/tcp` under the PORTS.

Also, I see many programmers use the docker file to launch the IBM Container. Should I switch to docker file instead of this IBM console web interface?

Comment: For checking if external ports are closed/open, I use [Open Port Checker](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). For local ports, you can use nmap. That can help you determine whether or not it is even open at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default ibm-liberty image on bluemix doesn't include sshd.  You could add it - you'll need to add supervisord, sshd, and the appropriate configuration for both into your Dockerfile.

Conversely, if what you really want is just a secure command line connection into your container, you can use [cf ic exec](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__exec) or docker exec.  (e.g. `cf ic exec -ti mycontainername bash` ) That'll give you a command line without having the overhead (and security exposure) of a running sshd.